# How can I enable a service only when it's installed in Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I was said to use the onlyif-parameter, but there doesn't seem to exist one for the service-type.

What can I do to enable this service only if it's installed? It's installed with a binary installer, so testing if the installation directory exists t

```
class scom {
    service { 'scx-cimd':
        ensure => running,
        enable => true,
        hasstatus => true,
        hasrestart => true,
        onlyif => "test -f /opt/microsoft/scx"
    }
}
```

The current error message is "Invalid parameter onlyif", because service doesn't have an onlyif parameter. What can I do to enable this service only if it's installation directory exists?

Answer (score 2):

The service type ([3.x](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.stable/type.html#service), [2.x](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.7.stable/type.html#service)) does not have an onlyif parameter, that is part of the exec type ([3.x](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.stable/type.html#exec), [2.x](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.7.stable/type.html#exec).

To do what you want to do, there are two ways. The first way is the normal and preferred way to do stuff. The second way is a hack that will work too, ideally the the chkconfig of the service should be a separate exec but there's no  harm in chkconfiging a service on even if it is already configured that way.

Option 1. Write a fact to see if the service is installed and put a conditional around the serivce type:

```
# service_scx_installed.rb
Facter.add('service_scx_installed') do
  setcode do
    File.exists?('/opt/microsoft/scx')
  end
end

# scom.pp
class scom {
  if $service_scx_installed {
    service { 'scx-cimd':
        ensure => running,
        enable => true,
        hasstatus => true,
        hasrestart => true,
    }
  }
}
```

Option 2. Put all of the logic in a big exec:

```
exec {'start and chkconfig on scx service':
  command  => 'chkconfig scx service on; service scx restart',
  onlyif   => ['test -f /opt/microsoft/scx', '! service scx status'],
  provider => 'shell',
}
```